# user in the proper group cannot copy files to a "drw-rwS---" dir

Tags: unix, file-permissions

This makes no sense to me: usr2 belongs to grpX, the directory is configured as bellow, so why can't usr2 copy his files to my folder? Is it because his files have different access settings? How can I chmod things so that this is never an issue (I want the files to inherit from my directory config)?

```
drw-rwS--- 2 usr1 grpX 4096 25 jun 18.28 data
```

Comment: What happens if you change "S" to "x"

Comment: It cannot be tested easily, this is on a large cluster and usr2 is simply not the type of person I can ask to do tests for me. I am just curious if I don't miss something obvious, if not I might bring the issue with the sys admins.

Comment: The owner `usr1` does not have `x` on the directory?  That is weird.  If you add that `x`, it all works.